# How to retrieve disk status description via winapi?

Tags: winapi

I want to get disk status which I can see in windows device manager: http://i.imgur.com/D1tZyTh.png

I've found the possible values here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738101%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Anyone knows how can I get those?

Regards

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @catzilla closest, but restricted attributes I've found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx